# Refresh (insert new) JTable rows 

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, odbc

I have a `JTable` in relation with SQL server and when I try to update a row, all cells update except the first one bacause this row is not in my constructor. So I tried to manually change it with 
            `tableAlbum.setValueAt(artistName, tableAlbum.getSelectedRow(), 0);`
but the table does not update. When I refresh manually the frame, the cell is correctly display with the right value.

Here is my code:

```
else if (e.getSource() == btnConfirm) {
    String artistName = (String) tableAlbum.getValueAt(tableAlbum.getSelectedRow(), 0);              
    tableAlbum.setValueAt(artistName, tableAlbum.getSelectedRow();
    modele.editAlbum(tableAlbum.getSelectedRow(), tile, price, genre, year, home, "");
```

There is my editMethod :

```
public void modifierAlbum(int num, String title, double price, String genre,
    String year, String home, String image) {

Album album = null;

    Statement statement;
    try {
        statement = connexion.createStatement();
        String query = "USE albums UPDATE Album SET title='"+title+"', price = "+price+", genre = '"+genre+"', year = '"+year+"', home = '"+home+"' WHERE titre = '"+title+"'";
        statement.executeUpdate(query);         

        album = new Album(title, price, genre, year, home);
        getData().set(num, album);
        fireTableRowsUpdated(0, data.size());

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is `setValueAt` on your `TableModel` firing an event? Take a look at [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire) of the trail page for `JTable`

Comment: Either you are doing database queries on the Event Dispatch Thread, or you are manipulating Swing objects on a worker `Thread`. While the first is allowed but just very bad practice, the latter is not even allowed. Best to correct that